# Parameterized Plan Flushed

Tags: sql-server-2016, plan-cache, recompile

I cannot find documentation anywhere on what would trigger this recompilation reason. We are investigating a sudden query performance drop and the only thing that I can think of is that the plan got recompiled for the parameterized query when executed against a small dataset which resulted in messing with row estimates. We noticed that when this process was running (after it started taking hours instead of seconds) it was hitting tempdb pretty hard. Statistics on consumed tables were not changed and the only other reason that makes sense in the list of recompilation reasons is #12 "Parameterized plan flushed".

The process in question was calling a view and filtering on a single INT column. This was done through Entity Framework.  There is only 1 Entity Key on the class and it is the PK of the main table in the view.   All records are unique.

I am curious if anyone can point me to any documentation out there that explains why a plan might be recompiled due to **"Parameterized plan flushed"**.

Comment: I would have thought it would calculate a new execution plan, but the old one should still be there. Have you got query store enabled? Did anything significant happen to the tables being queried? Large inserts, updates or deletes?

Comment: We do not have Query Store enabled.   I am still researching the performance impact of that feature.  

I have to look at the data in each table that the view accesses more closely to determine data changes, but there definitely were not enough changes to warrant statistics auto-updating as I did verify statistics on those tables did not change.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason for having statistic auto update disabled then i would reccomend you turn on autoupdate. Going back to yr post: I would be more interested about why you are now getting a "bad" plan.

Comment: ^^IMO it doesnt really matter why you got a new plan, the important bit is that the new plan performs badly. You need to find out why sql chose it so you can do something about it. Query Store would be very useful in helping monitor and diagnose this. The over head is minimal.

Comment: We do have AutoUpdate enabled for statistics.  In researching why the plan would have changed/been flushed, I first thought that maybe statistics on one of the tables consumed by the view were auto-updated, but that is not the case.

Comment: As far as why SQL chose the new plan, my initial guess was that after the flush, the next time the process ran was for our smallest client, then when it ran for our 2 largest clients, estimates were way off causing spills to tempdb.  We tested this by doing a restore of prod into a test environment, running our nightly processes for our smallest client then running them for our largest.  But it performed just fine, which threw us for a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query Plans are flushed from the cache for several reasons, including being aged out, being flushed due to memory pressure, flushed due to user action (DBCC FREEPROCCACHE etc), flushed due to restart and flushed due to explicit recompilation (OPTION (RECOMPILE or sp_recompile).

If you can see no evidence of forced recompilation or a manual flush, then it is most likely the plan was aged out or it was flushed due to memory pressure. [From Docs: Plan Cache Internals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc293624(v=technet.10)):

> Evicting plans from cache is based on their cost. For adhoc plans, the
>   cost is considered to be zero, but it is increased by one every time
>   the plan is reused. For other types of plans, the cost is a measure of
>   the resources required to produce the plan. When one of these plans is
>   reused, the cost is reset to the original cost. For non–adhoc queries,
>   the cost is measured in units called ticks, with a maximum of 31. The
>   cost is based on three factors: I/O, context switches, and memory.
>   Each has its own maximum within the 31-tick total.
>
> - I/O: each I/O costs 1 tick, with a maximum of 19.
> - Context switches: 1 tick each with a maximum of 8.
> - Memory: 1 tick per 16 pages, with a maximum of 4.
>
> When not under memory pressure, costs are not decreased until the
>   total size of all plans cached reaches 50 percent of the buffer pool
>   size. At that point, the next plan access will decrement the cost in
>   ticks of all plans by 1. Once memory pressure is encountered, then SQL
>   Server will start a dedicated resource monitor thread to decrement the
>   cost of either plan objects in one particular cache (for local
>   pressure) or all plan cache objects (for global pressure).

Take a look at this [StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151140/can-a-plan-age-reach-zero) which provides heaps of great links and information on plan reuse and caching. You'll have to put in place monitoring to catch the exact cause if this reoccurs, but you should also look at leveraging [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) which will allow you to force a known good plan for this query and track regressions across your database as this may be affecting other queries as well.

Comment: Any thoughts on performance implications of enabling Query Store?   I have read a variety of different experiences from people.  We have a heavy ad-hoc load because we use Entity Framework so I feel like we would need to set up Query Store to capture ALL as opposed to AUTO and it seems this can cause performance degradation.

Comment: With ad-hoc heavy, what you can find is Query Store can grow quite large because it stores all the queries and with ad-hoc heavy workloads this means a lot of queries and plans being stored. Typically, the performance impact isn't huge as the process is asynchronous and MS did a good job of not letting QS consume excess resources, but I have seen some systems suffer from excessive QS related waits once the store got too big.